# How can I put a range in Function 'Filter' in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark

I worked on below code and I noticed that my function does not show the expected result:
So the Python Command is:

```
>>> counts = textFile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
... .filter(lambda x : x<="94") \
... .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
... .reduceByKey(add)
>>> output = counts.collect()
>>> for (word, count) in output:
...    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

so above code really does not show numbers less than 94.
I thought it maybe is because of "" around the 94 but I figured out it is not.
So I tested by adding another number to make sure it has a range, So I modified the code Like below:

```
>>> counts = textFile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
... .filter(lambda x : x<="94" and x>="60") \
... .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
... .reduceByKey(add)
>>> output = counts.collect()
>>> for (word, count) in output:
...    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

And Now the answer is really between 94 and 60,

The questions:
1)Why the first one does not work? Should really need have it in a range like between 50 and 100?

2)So I know in flatmap we have keys and values, Can i just simply write something like in second line?,

```
.filter(lambda x : x<="94" and x>=x[0]) \
```

Thanks,

**First Update:**

So the "94" is string and I was thinking about using int(x) but it did not work.

I have some bunch of numbers and I want to say less than 94( x<="94")

I tried int(x) and I got an error when I tried to say counts.collect()

I thought or assume this may need a range so I tried to use x[0] as the left side of range but still doesn't work.
This code works correct and give me the answer since I know the 60 is the lowest number in my example.

```
>>> counts = textFile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
... .filter(lambda x : x<="94" and x>="60") \
... .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
... .reduceByKey(add)
>>> output = counts.collect()
>>> for (word, count) in output:
...    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

But this code does not work properly and shows all numbers(Like there is no condition):

```
>>> counts = textFile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
... .filter(lambda x : x<="94") \
... .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
... .reduceByKey(add)
>>> output = counts.collect()
>>> for (word, count) in output:
...    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```

**second Update:**

Below code is work with Scala, But I am wondering about pyspark
, Why it does not work properly in oyspark

```
filter(lambda x: int(x)<=94)
```

Comment: What is the type of your data? `"94"` is a string, and it is different than `94`. Please provide a [mcve] that recreates your issue. Provide a small sample rdd and demonstrate the problem you are experiencing.

Comment: @pault I added extra details in question, may you please check?Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In filter transformation, try below:

`filter(lambda x: int(x)<=94)`

Update (Sample Code):

```
from operator import add

text = ['1 2 3 4 1 23 5 5 43 54']
textFile = sc.parallelize(text)
counts = textFile.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' '))\
    .filter(lambda x: int(x) <= 5)\
    .map(lambda x: (x, 1))\
    .reduceByKey(add)

output = counts.collect()

for (word, count) in output:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))

4: 1
3: 1
1: 2
5: 2
2: 1
```

Comment: I added extra details in question

Comment: I think this work with scala , But how about pyspark?

Comment: I tested this code in pyspark, it works. Provide some sample data on which your logic does not work.